# Gradle bootRun from parent folder in multi-module project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have my `Gradle` *project*, which has 2 modules: *project A* and *project B*, where the latter depends on the former. Note that both projects are `Spring Boot` applications, so when I execute `gradle bootRun` from their respectives directories, they will start fine.

The problem is that I want to start, from parent directory, the service of *project A* when I execute `gradle bootRun`, and it is starting *project B*. It seems that I am missing some `Gradle` config.

**build.gradle (project A)**

```
group = 'com.oni'
version = '0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8



dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA'
    testCompile("de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo")
}
```

---

**build.gradle (project B)**

```
group = 'com.oni'
version = '0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    def withoutInflux = { exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb' }

    compile project(':projectA'), withoutInflux
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.9.7'
}
```

---

**build.gradle(parent)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
//        mavenLocal()
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        compile('org.influxdb:influxdb-java')
        compile('org.mockito:mockito-core')
        compile('ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:1.4.2')
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03'
    }
}
```

---

**settings.gradle(parent)**

```
rootProject.name = 'project'


include 'projectA'
include 'projectB'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can run this by using

```
./gradlew :projectA:bootRun
./gradlew :projectB:bootRun
```

Comment: Is it the point of the question to have one single bootRun for all modules in the project?